# Issue while Cropping using class.upload.php

Tags: php, jcrop

I am having a strange issue while cropping an image with JCrop and class.upload.php. I am not getting the image cropped as per the selection.
, I am working based on this demo http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos/crop.php.
I am using the below code to get the co ordinates using JCrop:

```
function updateCoords(c)
{
   $('#x').val(c.x);
   $('#y').val(c.y);
   $('#w').val(c.x2);
   $('#h').val(c.y2);
};
```

and I am posting these values to crop.php and using this code to crop the image (the code in the demos source is not working (saying deprecated), so I downloaded the latest class.upload.php file from net and wrote the below as per their documentation:

```
$handle->image_precrop =  array(intval($_POST['y']), intval($_POST['w']),intval($_POST['h']), intval($_POST['x']));
```

Comment: Are you sure that the order of the array you are creating is y, w, h, x? Is normally x, y, w, h..

Comment: did you check if anything's being posted? `var_dump($_POST)`.

Comment: @DavidConde the w and h are not width and height, they are x2 and y2 parameters in this case, initialy i used width and height, but i was getting an deprecated error with class.upload.php, so i took their new version, and there it was x2 and y2.

Comment: @MarcB yes the files are uploading properly, the problem is if i tried to crop in the size 0 0 279 300, i will be geting 279 x 320 image :). this is the problem